# Support custom file extension in a flutter app ( Open file with extension .abc in flutter )

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So I am exporting a file created in my application with extension .abc

Now, if the user shares the file on whatsapp or telegram or any other platform and when other user tries to open the file, the "open with" dialog should appear with my application in the list.

I have tried following approach which does not work plus it is only for Android and I am looking for multi-platform solution to this.

[Is it possible to register a Flutter app as an Android Intent Filter and to handle Incoming Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506533/is-it-possible-to-register-a-flutter-app-as-an-android-intent-filter-and-to-hand)

I was able to compile the app using above method but could not populate "Open with" dialog with my app's name

Thank you for your time.

EDIT 1:

So I have successfully added this functionality for android but I am still trying to add the same functionality for my iPhone users.

Can someone please help me with swift code part in iOS ??
I am not familiar with swift language but I want my users to be able to use same functionality on both platforms.

Comment: How did you do it for Android? What was missing from your link above?

Comment: Did you find any solution for both?

Comment: Typical stackoverflow. Nevermind I fixed it. Everyone else is just ?_?

Comment: xD. I will add the answer for Android below in a while

Answer (score -2):

I have found a solution for iOS:

You can use the [Uni Links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package to get the notifications into your Flutter app.
You then need to manually add the file types in the Info.plist for the XCode project. You can find an explanation for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290).