# How to open a file with a custom file extension from another app with my Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-intent

I need my Flutter app to be associated with the file type `.foo`. So that if a user opens their local file manager for example, and clicks on the file `bar.foo` android prompts them to open the file with my flutter app.

So far I understand, that this is basically an incoming Android intent which has to be registered with a so called `intent-filter` as described here: [Creating app which opens a custom file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577860/creating-app-which-opens-a-custom-file-extension).
But further, I do not understand how to handle it in Kotlin.

Therefore the next logical thing would be to find out [how incoming intents work in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter). The documentation however doesn't help me, as it is explained only in [Java and not Kotlin](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/5611). I have no experience with Java at all and would like to stick to Kotlin anyway, because I have other platform specific code written in Kotlin.

In this post *Deep Shah* seems to have the same problem, but doesn't share the solution:
[Support custom file extension in a flutter app ( Open file with extension .abc in flutter )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338213/support-custom-file-extension-in-a-flutter-app-open-file-with-extension-abc-i).

This post by *Shanks* died quietly: [Open custom file extension with Flutter App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162148/open-custom-file-extension-with-flutter-app).

I hope to find answers or pointers to relevant resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I [found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59484832/15614063) for android. This post should bundle all important steps into one. The things starting with `YOUR_` are dependant on you. Change them accordingly.

First, you have to register the `intent-filter` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. This will tell android to list your app as a possible option.

```xml
<!-- TODO: CHANGE ICON AND LABEL HERE -->  
<intent-filter android:icon="YOUR_ICON_LOCATION"                  
               android:label="YOUR_APP_LABEL"
               android:priority="1">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <!-- TODO: CHANGE FILE EXTENSION -->  
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.YOUR_FILE_EXTENSION" />
</intent-filter>
```

Next, set up your Android Method Channel. For this, in Kotlin it is done like so:

```kotlin
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    // TODO: CHANGE METHOD CHANNEL NAME
    private val CHANNEL = "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME"

    var openPath: String? = null
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        val channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "getOpenFileUrl" -> {
                    result.success(openPath)
                }
                else -> result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        handleOpenFileUrl(intent)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        handleOpenFileUrl(intent)
    }

    private fun handleOpenFileUrl(intent: Intent?) {
        val path = intent?.data?.path
        if (path != null) {
            openPath = path
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, set up a handler on the dart side of things. The following code has to be in a drawn Widget. I placed it into my `MainView` widget, as it is always drawn on app startup and is relatively high up in the Widget tree. (For me it is the first Widget outside the `MaterialApp` Widget)

```dart
class MainView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainViewState createState() => _MainViewState();
}

class _MainViewState extends State<MainView> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  // TODO: CHANGE CHANNEL NAME
  static const platform = const MethodChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME");
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getOpenFileUrl();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      getOpenFileUrl();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: Implement Build Method
  }

  void getOpenFileUrl() async {
    dynamic url = await platform.invokeMethod("getOpenFileUrl");

    if (url != null) {
      setState(() {
        // TODO: DO SOMETING WITH THE FILE URL
      });
    }
  }
}
```

After completely killing and restarting both my app and the external app (in my case the file manager) it worked.